# How to exclude some post from admin edit screen

Tags: admin

I want to restrict which post appears in a user edit screen based on its role. The roles are mapped to category.

2. I am trying to add some conditions at the time posts are retrieved so that only posts belonging to a specific category are shown in the edit screen.
3. I am not able to find out the appropriate hook to fire. I tried 'pre_get_posts' and then try to modify the query which satisfies the condition
    `if (is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {`
   but to no use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're having trouble with `pre_get_posts` as that is the correct hook to use. For example, if we wanted to restrict the `edit.php` screen to only show posts from authors when the current user is an author we could say:

```
/**
 * Pre Get Posts
 * Restrictions by Role
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function wpse378774_pgp( $query ) {
    
    // Return Early - Not Admin Panel
    if( ! is_admin() ) {
        return;
        
    // Return Early - Not Main Query
    } else if( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }
    
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    
    // Return Early - User not an author
    if( ! in_array( 'author', (array)$user->roles ) ) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Limit all queries to only show posts by author
    if( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        
        // Get all user IDs who are authors
        $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array(
            'role'      => 'author',
            'fields'    => 'ID',
        ) );
        $user_ids = $user_query->get_results();
        
        // Set our query modifier
        $query->set( 'author__in', $user_ids );
        
    }
    
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse378774_pgp' );
```

For more information please review [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) and [WP_User_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/).